# ServiceStack.OrmLite: StringLengthAttribute.MaxText produces "LONGTEXT" - how can I set to "TEXT"?

Tags: mysql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Using ServiceStack's OrmLite and decorating a Property with the following attribute, creates a column of type LONGTEXT, instead o TEXT as noted in the docs:

[image]

But it becomes LONGTEXT:

[image]

I tried setting the `StringLenghtAttribute` to something else, `65535`, `70000`, `Int32.MaxValue` etc, but it either interpretet it as a VARCHAR and gave me the `Column length too big` or `Row size too large`, or it became a LONGTEXT.

Question is: how can I force it to become "TEXT" (or any other text type in mysql)?

I could perhaps modify the `MaxColumnDefinition` and set it to `TEXT` but then I will never get LONGTEXT I assume.

[image]

### Update

Setting the `MaxColumnDefinition` to TEXT didn't change a thing.

Can I decorate the class with an attribute, specifying the type somehow? Or is that too sql-version-specific?

Or perhaps I should override the `GetColumnDefinition` and implement my own logic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Please note that this solution produces other problems that I will ask in a separate SO post)*

After some more research, it was solved creating my own StringConverter, as can be seen below:

```
public class MyStringConverter : StringConverter
{
    public override string GetColumnDefinition(int? stringLength)
    {
        if (stringLength.GetValueOrDefault() == StringLengthAttribute.MaxText)
            return MaxColumnDefinition;

        if (stringLength.GetValueOrDefault(StringLength) <= 255)
        {
            return UseUnicode
            ? $"NVARCHAR({stringLength.GetValueOrDefault(StringLength)})"
            : $"VARCHAR({stringLength.GetValueOrDefault(StringLength)})";
        }
        else if (stringLength.GetValueOrDefault(StringLength) <= 65535)
        {
            return $"TEXT";
        }
        else
        {
            return "LONGTEXT";
        }
    }
}
```

I also suggest setting the default StringLength to something smaller than the default 8000:

```
StringConverter converter = OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.GetStringConverter();
converter.StringLength = 255;
```

This way, the default `string` will be `varchar(255)`. If you want to make a specific string property something else, then set the attribute according to the `MyStringConverter`:

```
type = typeof(tWorks.Core.CoreCommons.ContactModuleProtocols.SMS.ModuleSettingsSMS);
type.GetProperty(nameof(MyClass.Prop1)).AddAttributes(new StringLengthAttribute(255)); // ==> varchar(255)
type.GetProperty(nameof(MyClass.Prop2)).AddAttributes(new StringLengthAttribute(500)); // ==> TEXT
type.GetProperty(nameof(MyClass.Prop3)).AddAttributes(new StringLengthAttribute(70000)); // ==> LONGTEXT
```

Comment: @mythz I run into another issue; a complex property like _public List<ActionInfo> gets a column of type _varchar(255)_ for some reason, which then gives an _Data too long for column_ error when trying to .Insert...