# ServiceStack.OrmLite: Implementing custom StringConverter affects column type of complex BLOB fields

Tags: mysql, blob, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

In a previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494824/servicestack-ormlite-stringlengthattribute-maxtext-produces-longtext-how-ca) I asked how I change the MySql column type when I have string properties in my POCOs.

The answer, which I answered myself, was to implement my own StringConverter. It was sort of an acceptable approach, I thought.

However, in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51496686/178143), I noted that not only was my `string` properties affected, so was all those properties that are complex and where OrmLite BLOBs them as JSON.

The field types for those complex columns in MySQL also became like `varchar(255)`, which of course doesn't last very long.

The StringConverter was very short and easy:

- I said that default string length is 255:

```js
StringConverter converter = OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.GetStringConverter();
    converter.StringLength = 255;
```

- I wanted string props defined as 255 chars or smaller to be `varchar(255)`
- string props defined as > 255 and < 65535 to be `text`
- string props defined as >= 65535 to be `longtext`

MyStringConverter:

```
public class MyStringConverter : StringConverter
{
    public override string GetColumnDefinition(int? stringLength)
    {
        if (stringLength.GetValueOrDefault() == StringLengthAttribute.MaxText)
            return MaxColumnDefinition;

        if (stringLength.GetValueOrDefault(StringLength) <= 255)
        {
            return UseUnicode
            ? $"NVARCHAR({stringLength.GetValueOrDefault(StringLength)})"
            : $"VARCHAR({stringLength.GetValueOrDefault(StringLength)})";
        }
        else if (stringLength.GetValueOrDefault(StringLength) <= 65535)
        {
            return $"TEXT";
        }
        else
        {
            return "LONGTEXT";
        }
    }
}
```

But, as stated above, a property that looks like this (ActionInfo just contains some strings and List):

```
public List<ActionInfo> _AvailableActions { get; set; }
```

produced a table like this when using MyStringConverter:

[image]

*Without* using `MyStringConverter`, the column became a `longtext`.

**Question is then: what am I missing?** I still want complex, BLOBed fields to become longtext so that JSON BLOBing can be done. I was hoping that the StringConverter only affected string properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column definition of blobbed complex types should use the [ReferenceTypeConverter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/76b0ced3e7ba42e4f01ef28025834ee3acaff8b5/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/Converters/SpecialConverters.cs#L114) which by default resolves to `DialectProvider.GetStringConverter().MaxColumnDefinition;`

You should inherit the RDBMS-specific `MySqlStringConverter` if you want to change the string behavior of MySQL Strings otherwise you will revert back to inheriting generic RDBMS behavior which uses `VARCHAR(8000)` for strings and `MaxColumnDefinition`.

Alternatively you can override `MaxColumnDefinition` in your own String converter:

```
public override string MaxColumnDefinition => "LONGTEXT";
```

Comment: Hmm, thats odd. I havent changed it. If I _do not_ register my own `MyStringConverter`, the MaColumnDefinition is `longtext`. If I register `MyStringConverter`, the MaxColumnDefinition is now `varchar(255)`, but it is not changed by me, in my code, as far as I can see...?

Comment: The `MaxColumnDefinition` seems to change based on the `StringLength` property in the `StringConverter`. If I manuallt change it to 255, then `MaxColumnDefinition` becomes `varchar(255)` because thats what my overridden `GetColumnDefinition` says. If I leave it, and standard is then 8000, the `GetColumnDefinition` will return `text` which is also what `MaxColumnDefinition` would return in my implementation, and so on. Basically, `MaxColumnDefinition` uses the method `GetColumnDefinition`? That is not what I expect or want.

Comment: That’s because you’re inheriting the generic StringConverter which doesn’t know about (I.e. can’t use) MySql data types. You should either inherit MySqlStringConverter or override MaxColumnDefinition to return what you want.

Comment: That didnt make it clearer to me: Longtext was used for complex blobbed types, so not sure why MaxColumnDefinition changed based on my implementation, shouldnt it be "static", always the same? 
It nonetheless worked if I just changed to MySqlStringConverter as you said. Thanks! Maybe you could update the answer with that =)